# SP 2013 Online Search - Include results from document library based on query string parameter

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-scope

I'm using REST API to get search results from a subsite. What I want to do is to include results from a particular Document Library based on if the property from the user's User Profile is set to `true`.

- If property1 = Yes - Include results from DocLib1
- If property1 = No - DO not include results from DocLib1

Is is possible to do ?

Comment: Is the document library located on the same subsite or is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd just have different REST urls with different parameters being passed. The queries would look something like this (not fully tested):

Include:
`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True'`

Exclude:
`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True+-Path:https:%2f%2ftenant.sharepoint.com%2fteams%2feric%2fShared%2520Documents'`

The key portion is `-Path:` to exclude items from the desired path.